JAVAX Mail - ERROR: 503 5.7.0 encryption too weak 0 less than 128
I'm stumped and not sure how to proceed. I am maintaining a legacy app and they want to convert the mail servers to TLS V1.2 and change the host. I am getting the following error -
DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending, THROW:  [7/3/24 13:41:40:006 PDT] 000021e5 SystemOut                                                    O com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 503 5.7.0 encryption too weak 0 less than 128 ; nested exception is:   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 503 5.7.0 encryption too weak 0 less than 128
pom.xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>

Code:
props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols","TLSv1.2");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25"); 
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        
// Get session
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
session.setDebug(true);
......Setting from,to
Transport.send(message);

I can see in the logs that connection to the server is good but I get the above error after that. Ive googled everywhere and I dont see aything with that specific error.
Anyone run into this before?
Tried changing the parameters in the properties but nothing has worked so far.
Auth is false.
And SSL has to be V1.2

The following may be necessary but not sufficient: The SMTP host you are sending to probably does not expect to receive SSL/TLS encrypted data on port 25 (props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");). Try port 587 instead, where SSL/TLS is typically enabled. You may see something like port 25, isSSL false in your debug data, as well. Port 465 may also be another option you can try. See also What SMTP port should you use?

As an aside (and this may be out of scope for you), you should also consider upgrading from javax packages to jakarta. You did tag your question as a jakarta-mail question!

Ah! I tried 587 and it doesnt connect. talked to our infrastructure team and it looks like our port is 25. I can try 465.
Will jakarta-mail be major changes in emailing or would it be simple as changing the pom?

jakarta-mail: Changes to the POM and changes to the Java import statements will be needed (e.g. from import javax.whatever to import jakarta.whatever. Maybe other things, but maybe not. Why not try for yourself on a small test program?

"our port is 25" - OK but "they want to convert the mail servers to TLS V1.2 and change the host" - so "they" need to sort that out first, before you can change your code, I expect.
